# Strange Emacs Colors in gray30 Background Urxvt

Tags: terminal-emacs, colors

Recently I've been trying out different terminal color schemes. However, I found out that when I change the background of `urxvt` to `gray30`, `emacs -nw` has completely different syntax coloring.

I've not found this with any other background color, and I can't find any information about why this happens. While I actually quite like these new colors, I'm very confused.

Questions:

1. How can I stop this behavior?
2. Do other people have the same experience?

Information:

- Version: Emacs 26.1
- Terminal: rxvt-unicode (urxvt) v9.22
- OS: Void Linux

The relevant part of my .Xdefaults reads:

```
! Colours:
URxvt.cursorColor: lightblue
! *background: #181818
*background: gray30
*foreground: #bbbbbb
```

The color changes happen irrespective of my shell, urxvt's foreground and cursor colors, and the font. 
The `ansi-color-name-vector` in my init file don't change. 
No other terminal program changes it's colors, and oddly, the modeline colors don't change either, but I do have a custom mode-line config.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: it's literally just `gray30` or is it lighter colors too?

Comment: Literally just gray30